# validate phone number for sms message in ios

Tags: ios, sms, phone-number

I know how to use the people picker api to get an email address from the address book and validate it as a valid email.  I am now trying to do the same with mobile phone numbers. The number would be stored and later passed to the sms messaging api.  How can I validate the number to ensure it can receive sms messages and work with all the different number formatting from different countries?

If it is not possible to be exact, I would rather allow a few numbers that fail at the send message stage, than reject numbers that are valid.

Comment: Perhaps this can help -> http://the-lost-beauty.blogspot.jp/2010/01/locale-sensitive-phone-number.html

Comment: that script looks interesting but requires all countries to be manually configured which I can't justify for this project.  Think I'll use a NSDataDetector to ensure it is a phone number and provide some instructions to the user indicating that it must be a mobile phone number.

Comment: well I got it working with the NSDataDetector, but was disappointed to find that the MFMessageComposeViewController just fails silently if you try to send an sms to a landline (controller returned MessageComposeResultSent).  So, I am still looking for some sort of mobile phone number validation in iOS.

Answer (score 0):

in libPhoneNumber-iOS (https://github.com/iziz/libPhoneNumber-iOS)

You can use this way

```
NBPhoneNumberUtil *phoneUtil = [NBPhoneNumberUtil sharedInstance];

NSError *aError = nil;
NBPhoneNumber *aPhoneNumber = 
    [phoneUtil parse:@"13111589979" defaultRegion:@"US" error:&aError];

NBEPhoneNumberType type = [phoneUtil getNumberType:myNumber];
BOOL isValidType = (type == NBEPhoneNumberTypeMOBILE);

BOOL isValidNumber = 
    [phoneUtil isValidNumber:myNumber] && [phoneUtil isViablePhoneNumber:myNumber];
```